# LessQL Like operator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lessql

I would like to compose a query this way:

```
$query = $orm->table();
              ->where('foo_id', $foo['id'])
              ->like('foo_name', '%DP') 
              ->fetch();
```

The error is:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: 
>       Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.like' doesn't exist in /var/www/webapp/app/vendor/morris/lessql/src/LessQL/Database.php:117

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: This code at least causes syntax error.

Comment: Slim PHP + LessQL *ORM

Answer (score 0):

You can make `LIKE` through the `where()` call:

```
$query = $orm->table()
          ->where('foo_id', $foo['id'])
          ->where('foo_name LIKE ?', array('%DP')) 
          ->fetch();
```